# How to print a function's arguments in the correct order?

Tags: python, arguments

I am trying to write in Python a function that whenever is called inside another function, say `f`, it prints the name of the function followed by the parameters with which it was called. As far as I know, `sys` can be imported, and `sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name` is the string with the function's name, and `sys._getframe(1).f_locals` is the dictionary containing variables names and values. The problem seems to be solved, but a minor issue concerning arguments puzzles me. Say I have

```
import sys
def f(a,b,c=0):
    print sys._getframe(1).f_locals
```

Then calling `f(1,2,3)` prints `{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}`, which is indeed correct. The problem is that dictionary entry `'c'` is listed before entry `'b'`, so that if I extract the values of the dictionary with `.values()` they are printed in the wrong order. My full example is something like

```
import sys
def caller():
    """ Prints name and args of the calling function, e.g. f(1,2,3)"""
    print sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name, tuple(sys._getframe(1).f_locals.values())

def f(a,b,c=0):
    caller()
```

Calling `f(1,2,3)` instead of printing `f(1,2,3)` prints `f(1,3,2)`. Why is the order messed up and how can I correct it?

Besides, is there a way not to print the default arguments that haven't been explicitly specified? E.g., in the above example I would like `f(1,2,3)` to print `f(1,2,3)` and `f(1,2)` to print `f(1,2)` instead of `f(1,2,0)`.

Comment: `locals()` outputs a dictionary, which are hashmaps at the lower level so are unordered. I suppose that you could use `inspect` to get the correct order?

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to Python, how would `inspect` work?

Comment: Ok, I did some searches and I came to the conclusion that `str(inspect.stack()[1][4])[2:-4]` might be what I am looking for. `inspect.stack()[1][4]` as far as I can tell print the exact code that called the function, even with comments and trailing newlines. That is why I have to trim the beginning and the end of the corresponding string. Does this solution have any bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the best way to have it in order, a `list` of `tuples`:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def name_and_args():
...     caller = inspect.stack()[1][0]
...     args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(caller)
...     return [(i, values[i]) for i in args]
... 

>>> def f(a, b, c):
...     print(name_and_args())
...

>>> f(1, 2, 3)
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

So just call the `name_and_args` function in every function as we have in `f`.

Comment: Great, thanks, but doesn't it work only inside `f`? I mean, I would like for every function to call a, say, `name_and_args()` function that prints name and args of the calling function. I think your example works only with `f` that has 3 arguments, doesn't it?

Comment: @AndreasT See edits. If I have been of assistance to you don't forget to upvote and accept!

Comment: @AndreasT New and improved so the function doesn't take any arguments and inspects the call stack! Let me know if it works!

Comment: Yes it works, thanks! Do you happen to know how I can refer to the caller of the caller? I mean, going up `2` levels as optional parameter `2` in `sys._getframe(2)` would do?

Comment: @AndreasT You could probably get the caller of the caller by doing `inspect.stack()[2][0]`. You should be able to do that with an optional parameter in your function.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! I couldn't figure out what the `[1]` was for. :)